# how to get specific tag related information from RDF file using SPARQL in java

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am using SPARQL to get tags related information from RDF file using java.below is my SPARQL query try to  read tags related information from RDF file.but it is not getting results.
my RDF file contains following information:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"   xmlns:c="http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/">
    <rdf:Description c:calaisRequestID="e35f8204-619c-e1cd-1403-db29b8d53276" c:id="http://id.opencalais.com/yrGQcSODPQmkcclcdKOwNg" rdf:about="http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/6ee25504-ff98-34e4-af60-dde69f5ddf73"><rdf:type rdf:resource="http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/sys/DocInfo"/>
    <c:document></c:document>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/6ee25504-ff98-34e4-af60-dde69f5ddf73/SocialTag/1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/tag/SocialTag"/>
    <c:docId rdf:resource="http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/6ee25504-ff98-34e4-af60-dde69f5ddf73"/>
    <c:socialtag rdf:resource="http://d.opencalais.com/genericHasher-1/4f9a3d55-33f5-3738-a2f7-3e9065a5a169"/>
    <c:name>Computing</c:name><c:importance>1</c:importance><c:originalValue>Computing</c:originalValue>
    </rdf:Description>
```

My SPARQL query:

```
 prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    prefix ctag: <http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/tag/SocialTag>
    prefix c: <http://s.opencalais.com/1/pred/>
    construct {
      ?tag c:name ?name ;
           c:importance ?importance .
    }
    where {
      ?tag a ctag:SocialTag ;
           c:name ?name ;
           c:importance ?importance .
    }
```

But i am not getting results how to do this please suggest me.

Comment: This appears to be a question about [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18017317/1281433) I gave to your previous question, [how to get specific tag related information from RDF file using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014074/how-to-get-specific-tag-related-information-from-rdf-file-using-java), which you said works (but still haven't accepted).  As @AndyS pointed out in an answer here, you've simply copied the SPARQL query from my answer incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

"ctag:" in your query is http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/tag/SocialTag (already has the SocialTag) so ctag:SocialTag is "http://s.opencalais.com/1/type/tag/SocialTagSocialTag" -- no match.

In general, if you do not get results, remove parts of the pattern until you do.  Using SELECT can be clearer until you have the pattern you want.